# Mudar a página inicial via htaccess

Tags: apache, htaccess

Galera quando acesso meu site o apache automaticamente carrega a página `index.php`.
É possível mudar isso no `htaccess`?

Quero que ele sempre busque a página `Login.php`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu htaccess tem de estar na root (public_html, creio eu). Tente assim no seu .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex Login.php
```

Comment: perfeito amigo, muito obrigado

Comment: De nada @HugoBorges

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ NomeDoArquivoAqui/$1 [L]
```

Em **NomeDoArquivoAqui** você põem o nome do arquivo que quer redirecionar, o `Login.php` por exemplo.